# separate logger for each instance of a library

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, logging, log4j

We have a plain old java library that is instantiated from many different applications. In this case each application is a web application that all live in the same tomcat container.

Each application logs to its own log file, using its own logger. We want the logs generated by the library, that are pertinent to a specific application, to also go to that applications separate log file.

For this, one way is to allow the application to pass in its logger to the library:

```
library = new library(Logger applicationsVeryOwnLogger);
```

And then use that logger, to log all statements in the library. However, this means that the logger is now a class variable in the library, and every class in the library needs a reference to the library to use the right logger.

Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar need in one of our older applications. The solution we came up with was a ResourceManager that would retrieve resources(Logger, Config files etc) by (context)ClassLoader.

Usually every application deployed as an EAR gets its own ClassLoader and the library can then just call ResourceManager.getLogger() to get the Logger associated with the current Thread/Application. That way you dont need to pass it with every method call in the library (it requires that you can change the library tho).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class ResourceManager 
{
    private static final Map<ClassLoader, Map<String, Object>> resources = 
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ClassLoader, Map<String, Object>>());
    public static final String LOGGER = Logger.class.getName();

    static
    {
        // adjust for log4j or other frameworks
        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("logging.default");
        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        logger.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler() 
        {
            {
                setOutputStream(System.out);
                setLevel(Level.ALL);
            }
        });
        registerResource(null, LOGGER, logger);
    }

    private static ClassLoader getApplicationScope()
    {
        return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    }

    public static void registerResource(final String name, final Object resource)
    {
        registerResource(getApplicationScope(), name, resource);
    }

    public static synchronized void registerResource(final ClassLoader scope, final String name, final Object resource)
    {
        Map<String, Object> hm = null;
        hm = resources.get(scope);
        if (hm == null)
        {
            hm = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Object>());
            resources.put(scope, hm);
        }
        hm.put(name, resource);
    }

    public static Object getResource(final String name)
    {
        for(ClassLoader scope = getApplicationScope();;scope = scope.getParent())
        {
            final Map<String, Object> hm = resources.get(scope);
            if ((hm != null) && hm.containsKey(name)) 
            {
                return hm.get(name);
            }
            if (scope == null) break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void registerLogger(final Logger logger)
    {
        registerResource(LOGGER, logger);
    }

    public static Logger getLogger()
    {
        return (Logger)getResource(LOGGER);
    }       
}
```

Register Logger in the init phase of EJB/WebApp(needs to be registered before any call to getLogger):

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger([Application Logger Name]);
ResourceManager.registerLogger(logger);
```

Retrieve Logger in library(utility method):

```
private Logger getLogger()
    {
        return ResourceManager.getLogger();     
    }
```

This will return the logger for the application(EAR) that is associated with the current thread.

Not limited to Loggers it also works for other resources that you want to share.

Limitations:

- wont work if you package multiple applications/EJBs per deployed EAR
- ResourceManager and Logging library need to be on the same or a higher ClassLoader than the library and application. If there is an option to bundle then Alexanders approach is cleaner. (we use java.util.logging which is by default on the server level so his approach doesnt work)

Comment: As a side note this solution can also be used to share all kinds of resources, not just loggers.

Comment: you might want to paste relevant sections of code in your answer, in case the link dies in the future.

Comment: One other thing to note about this method is that ResourceManager.registerLogger() must be called before the library is instantiated. Otherwise, the class loggers will all be set using the default logger. This can be a deal breaker for some implementations.

Comment: It is not necessary to call it before the library is instantiated, only before the library calls getLogger().

Comment: @prmatta Inlined the code and removed unrelated sections + generification. Not sure if i could remove some of the synchronization i am not an expert and somewhat defensive there.

Answer (score 3):

You've marked your question with `log4j` tag, so I assume that's what you are using.

I hope that your library is using a unique package name.

If that's the case, you can actually just setup a logger for that package.

```
log4j.category.my.lib.package = INFO, libFileAppender
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, rootFileAppender
```

Doing so will log messages from your library to both **libFileAppender** and **rootFileAppender**.

If you don't want to messages from your library to appear in **rootFileAppender** you may turn off that logger additivity, like this:

```
log4j.category.my.lib.package = INFO, libFileAppender
log4j.additivity.my.lib.package = false
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, rootFileAppender
```

With this, you will only see message in **libFileAppender**

Comment: I don't think this meets the requirements. With this every log from the library can be redirected to one place. However, we need each log from the library that is generated by a specific application to go to one place (which is the application's log file).

Comment: @prmatta. Throw this file into WEB-INF/classes and setup appender that is specific for that application and each application will log the library calls to that appender. I don't see how it does not meet your requirements.

Comment: Arnt the Loggers/Appenders for log4j managed on a JVM level? And if you use the same name for all loggers (which you have to because the library needs the name) then you keep registering the same logger.

Comment: @Stefan. OP said that he's running in Tomcat. Throw log4j.jar into your app's `lib` folder and you will get separate logging per context.  The application's install/initialization job is to make sure that rootLogger appender does not use the same file name.  To me this task is trivial, as you can use context name as a root name for file appender and servlet container makes sure that you don't have 2 contexts with the same name.

Comment: @Alexander Pogrebnyak this would also require that the library is bundled with each app. So you cant just 'install' log4j and library jars on the webserver and use it with every app you deploy, you always have to bundle.

Comment: @Stefan. Yes, you always have to `bundle`, and that's not a bad thing, because then you `bundle` only versions of libraries that you've tested your code with, and do not depend on what's installed in the environment.  If you don't trust me, read tomcat's documentation on logging -> http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html, especially this line: `These steps are not needed if you just want to use log4j in your own web application. — In that case, just put log4j.jar and log4j.properties into WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes of your web application.`

Comment: @Alexander Its not about trusting ;). But it needs to be mentioned, different places different requirements. Here at work we dont bundle common libraries at all. Also this approach does not work properly if multiple logical applications are bundled within one EAR(just like my approach).

Comment: I must say, both solutions are well thought of and work. Alexanders solution has the benefit of not requiring any code changes. But it does require knowledge/control of how the applications are packaged. Stefan's solution has the advantage of not needing to know how the application is packaged - but it does require code changes in the library.